# Parse Nested json using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can i parse the following Json using DataContractJsonSerializer

{"Jack":{"accountId":407,"accountType":"TWITTER"},
"Mark":{"accountId":407,"accountType":"TWITTER"},
"John":{"accountId":407,"accountType":"TWITTER"},
"407":{"accountId":407,"accountType":"TWITTER"}

}

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to implement a class that represents this JSON data. Then you need to create an instance of the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, and then call the `ReadObject` method to perform the deserialization.

Although [this post](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx) refers to .NET 3.5, I think it should still help you out on WP7.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar kind of an problem. I used nested Dictionaries. Something like this -

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>
```

Then I looped through the deserialised object to get the values.